# Phonegab Data retrieval

Tags: database, cordova, connection

I am new to phonegap development and my question is how to display data from a database to my phonegap application? There are many similar questions but none of them is pointing to the correct solution.

Comment: which database you are talking about ? local database or remote ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the data using web services. or local, you can use SQLite